# Can I refer to the image width and height in an argument?

Tags: imagemagick, imagemagick-convert

I want to convert multiple images into square format, filling any empty space with black. Assuming the images have a width of 1000 and a height of less than 1000 (or vice versa), I can do it like this (using PowerShell):

```
magick.exe convert -background black -gravity center `
-resize 1000x1000 -extent 1000x1000 `
-set filename:original '%t' '.\*.jpg' './%[filename:original]-resized.jpg'
```

However, I want this to work for arbitrarily sized images. I need to do something like this, which is not an actually supported syntax:

```
#...
-resize 'max(%w,%h)xmax(%w,%h)' -extent 'max(%w,%h)xmax(%w,%h)' `
# ...
```

Is there an Imagemagick syntax for what I'm trying to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Imagemagick 7, use `magick`, not `magick convert` and move the input parameter to the first parameter position, i.e. `magick '.\*.jpg'`.

Then, to do what you want change

```
-resize 'max(%w,%h)xmax(%w,%h)' -extent 'max(%w,%h)xmax(%w,%h)'
```

to

```
-resize "%[fx:max(w,h)]x%[fx:max(w,h)]" -extent "%[fx:max(w,h)]x%[fx:max(w,h)]"
```

Comment: What do you mean by "use magick not magick convert and not convert"? If I run `magick.exe -background black...` I get the error `no images found for operation \`-resize' at CLI arg 5 @ error/operation.c/CLIOption/5448`.

Comment: What is your IM version and platform (presumably Windows)?  What do you get from `magick.exe -version`? If nothing or error, then `convert.exe -version`.  IM 7 uses magick in place of convert which is IM 6 syntax.  You can use magick convert, but then will not get IM 7 new features because it is calling convert which is is IM 6.

Comment: It's 7.1.0. But I found the issue: If omitting `convert`, the input parameter (`'.\*.jpg'` in my case) must be moved to the first parameter position. I.e. `magick.exe '.\*.jpg' -background black...`. I'll edit your post so it can be marked as the accepted answer.

Comment: That is correct. IM 7 is more strict on syntax. Read the input first, then any settings, then any operators that use the settings, then the output.  IM 6 was very forgiving and many people use normal Unix syntax, which formally is not correct, to read the arguments before the input and output.