# How to resize image width but keep original height?

Tags: shell, terminal, imagemagick

```
convert input.png -resize 200x output.png
```

resizes the input image's width to be 200 pixels, but it also resizes the height to ensure the output has the same aspect ratio as the input.

I would like the output to have the same height as the input image instead. The output should be squashed/stretched as necessary.

E.g. if the input is 400x365 pixels, then the output should be 200x365 pixels. But if the input is 12151x832 pixels, the output should be 200x832 pixels.

According to https://stackoverflow.com/a/75380906/3310334 I've already tried

```
magick input.png -resize 200x'%h' output.png
```

But this also keeps the aspect ratio, the output image's height is not the same as the input image's height.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `!` flag like this:

```bash
magick input.png -resize 200x\! output.png
```

More on documentation: https://imagemagick.org/Usage/resize/#noaspect

Answer (score 0):

Explicitly declaring the image height can avoid this.

```bash
height=$(identify -format "%h" input.png)
convert input.png -resize 200x$height\! output.png
```